# Замена комбинаций символов вида '\n' на спецсимволы

Tags: lua

Задача -- обработать аргумент командной строки как рядовую строку lua.

Т.е. заменить комбнации вида `\n`, `\a` и проч. на соотв. символ (перевод строки/звонок/проч.).

Это может быть и код символа (`\000`, к примеру).

Как такую замену можно сделать, используя только `string.gsub` (без `load`/`loadstring`)?

Comment: А в чём сложность? Сам вопрос уже содержит ответ: ловить по подходящему паттерну и заменять.  Паттерн, например, такой: `\\((.)%d?%d?)`

Comment: @Egor: И на что менять?

Comment: Как и написано в вопросе, "на соотв. символ (перевод строки/звонок/проч.)". Используя таблицу замен.  Точнее, тут нужна функция замен, чтобы переводить цифры в код символа (`gsub` принимает функцию или таблицу третьим аргументом).  Кстати, в луа начиная с 5.2 есть ещё вот такие символы: `\x00`, поэтому набор замен зависит от версии )))

Comment: Кстати, на англоязычном SO такие простые вопросы по луа как этот получают по 2-3 ответа в первый же день из-за наличия достаточного кол-ва "охотников за репутацией".  И там общество очень доброжелательно, люди терпимы к незнанию тобою англ языка и к незнанию чего-то другого тоже, можно не знать язык и тупо пользоваться только гуглопереводчиком.  Только нужно показать свои усилия решить задачу самостоятельно - написать в вопросе свой набросок (скелет) кода, пусть даже неправильного.  Попробуй начать писать свой код с `gsub`-ом.

Comment: Ну, это все ясно, с функцией-то не понятно.

Comment: Сначала прочитай мануал про функцию внутри gsub, потом попытайся написать код.  Чтобы другие поняли, в каком месте ты застрял на пути решения.  Вопросы типа "решите за меня задачку целиком" не вызывают положительных реакций.

Comment: Уже читал, знаю. Но не ясно, с какого краю подступиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38812/discussion-between-val-and-egor-skriptunoff).

Comment: Можно передавать строку в е-параметре: `lua -e 'msg="abc\n\38def"' program.lua`, тогда внутри программы `program.lua` можно пользоваться переменной `msg`, которая уже инициализирована строкой "abc\n\38def".

Comment: @Skrip, по сути дела, это тоже `load`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, так:

```lua
-- массив, содержащий двухэлементные массивы с парами замен.
-- приведены для иллюстрации только три пары.
-- остальные литералы перечислены, например, здесь: 
-- https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html
a = {
   { '\\n', '\n' }
  ,{ '\\r', '\r' }
  ,{ '\\a', '\a' }
}
-- получаем первый аргумент программы
s = arg[1]
-- цикл по массиву a 
for k,v in pairs (a) do
  -- заменяем первый элемент пары на второй
  s = string.gsub (s, v[1], v[2])
end
-- замена восьмеричных констант вида \123
s = string.gsub (s,
  '\\(%d%d%d)', 
  function (o) return string.char(tonumber(o, 8)) end
)
-- замена шестнадцатиричных констант вида \xab
s = string.gsub (s,
  '\\x(%x%x)',
  function (h) return string.char(tonumber(h, 16)) end
)
-- отладочный вывод 
io.write (s)
```

проверка:

```
$ lua test.lua '\a\n\r\123\xab' | hd
00000000  07 0a 0d 53 ab                                    |...S.|
00000005
```

---

как справедливо отмечают в комментариях, для последовательности трёх восьмиричных цифр лучше использовать шаблон `[0-7][0-7][0-7]` вместо `%d%d%d`.

Comment: Пока что не принимаю, в случае отсутствия других ответов даю награду.

Comment: в луа нет восьмеричных констант, \ddd десятичные.  и они не обязательно 3-значные, можно написать "\0"

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, *десятичные* — справедливо. я дополнил ответ. // *не обязательно трёхзначные* — я ориентировался на [сишные стандарты](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences). но, думаю, реализовать и [прочие варианты](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC3) при необходимости труда не составит. я ведь просто показал возможные концепции, а не «решение под ключ». // кстати, если у вас есть время и желание, вы можете написать ещё один ответ, с «решением под ключ».

Comment: Хм, впервые слышу о том, что string.gsub поддерживает захваты. Ответ принял, пометил для награды.

Comment: Думаю, шаблон `[0-7][0-7]?[0-7]?` подойдёт.